# Pandas: Trying to edit data in a row for a list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of 3 DataFrames `x`, where each DataFrame has 3 columns. It looks like

```
1   2   T/F
4   7   False
4   11  True
4   20  False
4   25  True
4   40  False
```

What I want to do is set the value of each row in column 'T/F' to `False` for each DataFrame in list `x`

I attempted to do this with the following code

```
rang = list(range(len(x))) # rang=[0,1,2]
for i in rang:
    x[i].iloc[:len(x), 'T/F'] = False
```

The code compiled, but it didn't appear to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much simpler. Just iterate over the actual dataframes and update the columns with:

```
for df in [df1, df2]:
    df['T/F'] = False
```

---

Als note that [`DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is a *integer-location based indexing*. If you want to index using the column names use `.loc`.